# How to change a marriage visit visa to a spouse visa?

Tags: united-kingdom, eu-spouses, tunisian-citizens

I have a marriage visit visa and it is MULT. I got it to get married in the UK last February. Now I am married and I left the UK to go back to my country. My husband is Italian living and working in the UK. We are planning to stay together in Birmingham where he is living.

Because I'm out of the UK and my visa still valid, may I enter the UK one more time and apply for EEA visa from there?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can, but I doubt it.  You do not in fact meet the requirements of a marriage visitor: when you enter the UK, you will be doing so without any intention to marry.  Furthermore, you don't seem to meet the requirement of being a visitor, because you intend to stay in the UK.  The requirements are listed on the [Marriage Visitor visa overview page](https://www.gov.uk/marriage-visa) and the [eligibility page](https://www.gov.uk/marriage-visa/eligibility).

Instead, you should apply for an [EEA family permit](https://www.gov.uk/family-permit).